# Joining raster and vector layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector

I have a raster layer (DTM of central Scotland) and a vector layer that shows the location of archaeological sites. I want to know how to join the layers so that I can figure out what height each archaeological site is at.

I have tried converting the raster layer into a vector layer and then doing a spatial joint but that does not seem to be working since when I polygonise the layer I seem to lose information.

Does anyone know how to "ask" QGIS what sites fall within what height or how to join a raster and a vector layer?

Comment: Are the archaeological sites polygon features or points?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Summing pixel values within polygon zone in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43425/summing-pixel-values-within-polygon-zone-in-qgis)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it really solves your issue, but I just read in another post about Zonal Statistics. Might that help?
https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html

Otherwise maybe the point sampling tool might help you. There you can extract the values in a point-grid of the raster file. And afterwards you could join the two polygones maybe? 
http://www.digital-geography.com/qgis-plugins-point-sampling-tool/

Good luck with it :)

Answer (score 1):

In case your archeological data are points, you might able to use `v.what.rast.points` from the GRASS processing toolbox.

The first thing is to have a field in the location vector to sotre the elevation data.

In my example I have a layer caled `ponts` and I add a field called `z` (a double with 3 decimals)

[image]

Then use the GRASS command `v.what.rast.points` as in the picture below. When I tried I had some trobles with the `where`argument, but then I just put a 1 state it is always true.

I left the parameter `Sampled` empty, so a new temporary layer was created. You could also overwrite the vector file with points, but it is a bit risky to try tools for the very first time with your data, better the long way.

[image]